# Python: Math expression parsing

Tags: python, parsing, math, expression, evaluate

Python:
So I am working on a program (which is a class assignment) that will take an expression such as 3/4/5 or 32432/23423/2354325 or 3425*343/254235 or 43252+34254-2435, etc(for all operators from +,-,/,*). and will solve the expression.

I CANT USE EVAL!!

I cant use higher level codes, I am limited to, at most, using string manipulators from the below website to split the string.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq

My method is to look at the expression the user enters and then use a find function to find the OPERATORS, and then use these operators and a slicing function (eg. s[0:x]). What I have is below and unfortunately it isnt working: *note that the print statements are in there for debugging purposes only.
EDIT: why is x not defined when I run the program and enter an expression?

```
z= (input("expression:")).strip()

def finding(z):
    if "/" in z:
        x=z.find("/")
        print("hi1")
    elif "*" in z:
        x=z.find("*")
        print("hi2")
    elif "+" in z:
        x=z.find("+")
        print("hi3")
    elif "-" in z:
        x=z.find("-")
        print("hi4")
    else:
        print("error, not math expression")
    return x

def Parsing(z,x):

    x= finding(z)
    qw=z.s[0:x]
    print (qw)
# take the x-value from function finding(z) and use it to split 

finding(z)
Parsing(z,x)
```

Comment: Didn't you ask [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055884/parsing-math-expression-in-python-and-solving-to-find-an-answer)? I know that I answered this exact question yesterday. Someone else did as well two days ago. Nobody is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Blender This is a completely different method that I am trying thats why it is in a new questions. You could always look at my profile and questions there to see what i've already asked before giving me a -1. I made a new question because the answers I was getting were getting far off track. I am asking something very very specific and giving the answer to it will not complete my homework therefore I didn't re-ask the same question so someone would do my homework....

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056137/464744)?

Comment: @Blender For the reasons above please reverse the negative rep. you gave me.

Comment: @Blender I stated in the post why I couldn't use the code. No one is looking at that post anymore and no one is giving any more feedback...

Comment: Have you tried to change that code to suit your needs?

Comment: @blender Yes I have, but I was unable to manipulate it and had to move on since I am not that advanced and didn't understand the code in that post completly. It is ludicrous to argue an old thread in a new one...I edited my post. If you consider that question to be cheating on my homework then alas it is impossible for me to learn computer science..

Comment: Didn't you just [ask this yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116167/python-creating-a-calculator/13116467#13116467)?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid No, of course not, not at all, negative. Please look at specifically what I am asking in this post. btw you never replied to my post in your answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just having trouble splitting the input into its parts, here's something to help you. I left it as readable as I could so that you could at least understand what it does. I'll explain any part of it if you need me to:

```
def parse(text):
    chunks = ['']

    for character in text:
        if character.isdigit():
            if chunks[-1].isdigit():   # If the last chunk is already a number
                chunks[-1] += character  # Add onto that number
            else:
                chunks.append(character) # Start a new number chunk
        elif character in '+-/*':
            chunks.append(character)  # This doesn't account for `1 ++ 2`.

    return chunks[1:]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> parse('123 + 123')
['123', '+', '123']
>>> parse('123 + 123 / 123 + 123')
['123', '+', '123', '/', '123', '+', '123']
```

I'll leave the rest up to you. If you aren't allowed to use `.isdigit()`, you'll have to replace it with lower-level Python code.

Comment: Nice, better than my attempt over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116167/python-creating-a-calculator/13116467#13116467)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It is a placeholder in the definition of the function I believe.

Comment: @blender yes I can use all the code. I understand that "text" is most likely an input outside of the definition of the function. I dont understand where the variable character fits in. it is not defined in the parameters of the function but it is being used in arguments.

Comment: `character` is defined within the `for` loop and by the `for` loop. Take a look here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Oh, I am so used to seeing "i" in place of character that I didn't realize...Anyways,The definition from the python documentation website creates ambiguity... I am assuming that character.isdigit() is an argument that states that: if "character" in "text" is a number, then move on to the indented line of argument.... is this a correct understanding of isdigit?

Comment: @user1716168: It could be just me, but this code isn't too far off from the plain English explanation of what you would do. `isdigit()` returns `True` if the string is composed only of digits `'1'.isdigit() == True`.

Comment: Would you mind joining me in chat?

Comment: @user1716168: You accidentally edited out the link

Comment: I never put a link... I have never used chat on this website but a prompt came up above asking me to move conversations to chat. Would you mind linking to one that I can join you in.

Comment: Oh wait, apparently I need 20 rep which I don't have yet.. Do you use anything else that youre willing to share? IRC, PM's, external messengers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18771/discussion-between-blender-and-user1716168)

Comment: @user1716168: I bumped your rep up slightly. See the link above.

Comment: But I have looked at it enough and it just clicked in my mind. Please check my understanding, I am going to start at the for loop. For "character" in "text", if the "character" is a digit and if the last chunk(last character?) was a digit, then add the next "character" in "text" to "chunk"? Repeat this until the character under consideration is no longer a digit. If it is no longer a digit then move to the elif statement, create a chunk there, and then move back to the original if statement. Since chunk[-1] is no longer a dgit move to else statement and repeat.Is this correct? I have a few Q'S

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for doing this, I think, is implementing a [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to convert your equation in postfix notation and then executing it from left to right.

But since this is a class assignment, you should do the actual implementation yourself, I already gave you more than I should have.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help at all. A user gave me a specific example in relation to your above method and I realized I am unable to use the method.

Comment: So why didn't you ask a question on that method and what you are having problems with instead of repeating your entire question again?

Comment: Actually it does fit your needs, it respects the priority of operations and it doesn't need any external libs, I know because I implemented this in Python in my spare time before.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why does no one understand that I did ask several time son my other post and people just stopped repyling... What am I to do then? The problem was never solved. I am sure it is not the nature of this site to leave a question unanswered.. Of course at least one person here will argue I am trying to cheat which is false.

Comment: @wiill my OP did not say I could use any built in function. It said I could use any STRING built in function... thus it does not suit my needs. damn Im getting so much heat...

Comment: I did it with arrays, strings and string built-in functions. Unless you're not allowed to use arrays, I don't see any problems. Also, don't take it wrong, I'm just trying to show you that my solution isn't that hard and I think it is worth trying. I could actually paste my code tomorrow if you really want. Don't expect anything beautiful though, I did it quick'n'dity.

Comment: I cannot use arrays/lists. Please don't post the code, I want to figure this out myself as much as possible.

Comment: Well it could be done using only strings, only it would be a little bit easier with lists. Also, I totally agree with not posting the code and letting you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is x not defined when I run the program and enter an expression?

`x` is not in scope, you only define it in your methods, and you try to access it elsewhere.

```
z= (input("expression:")).strip()

def finding(z):
    # ... removed your code ...
    # in this method, you define x, which is local
    # to the method, nothing outside this method has
    # access to x
    return x

def Parsing(z,x):

    x= finding(z) # this is a different x that is assigned the 
                  # return value from the 'finding' method.
    qw=z.s[0:x] # I'm curious as to what is going on here.
    print (qw)
# take the x-value from function finding(z) and use it to split 

finding(z) # here, z is the value from the top of your code
Parsing(z,x) # here, x is not defined, which is where you get your error.
```

Since `Parsing` is already calling `finding` to get the value of `x`, you don't need to pass it into `Parsing`, you also don't need to call `finding(z)` outside `Parsing`, since you don't store the value anywhere.

```
def Parsing(z):

    x= finding(z) # this is a different x that is assigned the 
                  # return value from the 'finding' method.
    qw=z.s[0:x] # I'm curious as to what is going on here.
    print (qw)
# take the x-value from function finding(z) and use it to split 

# finding(z)  -- not needed 
Parsing(z)
```

Comment: How would I get the X that is in the first function into the second function?

Comment: Since you are calling the first function in the second function, and storing the result `x = finding(z)` you already have it in the second function.